# Mobile detect Innerhtml in php code functions.php

Tags: php, mobile, innerhtml, detect

In my functions.php wordpress file i have following code:

```
function mia_on_load_script()
{
    // Not our page, do nothing
    if( !is_page( 'test' ) )
        return;
?>

    <script type="text/javascript">
function change1(){
  document.getElementById('mydiv').innerHTML = '<div id="1" style="margin-left: 0px; padding: 0px; float: left; width: 640px; height: 392px; border: 0px;"><iframe style="border: 0 none transparent;" src="//www.ustream.tv/embed/******?wmode=direct&amp;autoplay=true" width="640" height="392" frameborder="no"></iframe></div><div id="2" style="margin-left: 0px; padding: 0px; float: left; width: 320px; height: 392px; border: 0px;"><iframe style="border: 0 none transparent;" src="//www.ustream.tv/socialstream/******" width="320" height="392" frameborder="no"></iframe></div><div id="addthisc" style="margin:0px; text-align: center; background-color:#0A0A0C; paddding: 0px 0px 0px 0px; width: 640px; height: 100%;  border:0px;"><div class="addthis_native_toolbox"></div></div>';
}
</script>


    <?php   
    };        
add_action( 'wp_head', 'mia_on_load_script' );

?>
```

Html code in webpage test is following:

```
<input type="button" onclick="change1()" value="change html in mydiv " />
```

This function change html in div: 'mydiv' clicking button "change html in mydiv "

Instead of change html clicking a button with javascript i want change it at load of webpage when request is made from a mobile browser so i 
have decided to use
 Mobile_Detect.php class (https://github.com/serbanghita/Mobile-Detect)

my previous function became:

```
function mia_on_load_script()
{
    // Not our page, do nothing
    if( !is_page( 'test' ) )
        return;
?>

         <?php   
 require_once(TEMPLATEPATH . '/MyScript/Mobile_Detect.php');
 $detect = new Mobile_Detect; 
 if ( $detect->isMobile() ) {
???????????????????????????????????????????????????????????
???????????????????????????????????????????????????????????
???????????????????????????????????????????????????????????
}

?>



    <?php   
    };        
add_action( 'wp_head', 'mia_on_load_script' );

?>
```

so which code i must insert in place of the question marks to change html in place of 'document.getElementById('mydiv').innerHTML'?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `window.addEventListener('load', ...)`:

```
function mia_on_load_script()
{
    if(is_page('test'))
    {
        require_once(TEMPLATEPATH . '/MyScript/Mobile_Detect.php');
        $detect = new Mobile_Detect; 
        if($detect->isMobile())
        {
?>

<script> <!-- No "type" attribute for HTML 5 -->
window.addEventListener('load', function()
{
    document.getElementById('mydiv').innerHTML = '<div id="1" style="margin-left: 0px; padding: 0px; float: left; width: 640px; height: 392px; border: 0px;"><iframe style="border: 0 none transparent;" src="//www.ustream.tv/embed/******?wmode=direct&amp;autoplay=true" width="640" height="392" frameborder="no"></iframe></div><div id="2" style="margin-left: 0px; padding: 0px; float: left; width: 320px; height: 392px; border: 0px;"><iframe style="border: 0 none transparent;" src="//www.ustream.tv/socialstream/******" width="320" height="392" frameborder="no"></iframe></div><div id="addthisc" style="margin:0px; text-align: center; background-color:#0A0A0C; paddding: 0px 0px 0px 0px; width: 640px; height: 100%;  border:0px;"><div class="addthis_native_toolbox"></div></div>';
});
</script>

<?php
        }
    }
}
add_action('wp_head', 'mia_on_load_script');
```